# Create an Unit Test for Generic Method

Tags: c#, xunit

I have the following class:

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T> {

  public T Minimum { get; set; }
  public T Maximum { get; set; }

  public Range(T minimum, T maximum) {
    Minimum = minimum;
    Maximum = maximum;
  }

  public Boolean Contains(T value) {
    return (Minimum.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (value.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0);
  }

}
```

I am using XUnit to create my Unit Tests ...

How should I test the Contains method that has T?

Comment: There is a limit how much you should test your class, I think it will be enough if you test your class with single type that implements `IComparable<T>` e.g. `int`, test all border cases for `int` and assume that it will work with other `IComparables<T>`, done.

Comment: If your class behaves uniformly for all `T` (which it should) then you can just supply a particular `T` (e.g. `int` in this case) for the test cases.

Comment: @csharpfolk that sounds reasonable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been stated, you could test it with an int which might look something like this:

```
var range = new Range<int>(minimum: 3, maximum: 7);
Assert.IsTrue(range.Contains(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of an IComparable and for thoroughness (true unit testing) I would suggest a mocking library with the ability to verify calls.  I would probably use something like Moq.  You will need an object that implements the interface, which you might have already or you could create a test one with no actual implemetation.

```
public class YourObject : IComparable<YourObject>
{
  public virtual int CompareTo(YourObject other)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

I would make a subtle change your Range code just a bit for consistency:

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{

  public T Minimum { get; set; }
  public T Maximum { get; set; }

  public Range(T minimum, T maximum)
  {
    Minimum = minimum;
    Maximum = maximum;
  }

  public Boolean Contains(T value)
  {
    return (Minimum.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (Maximum.CompareTo(value) >= 0);
  }
}
```

The end result is identical but it makes things a bit easier while setting up the mocks.  Or you could go with value.CompareTo on both accounts.  Either way it would add a little more consistency.

The test code would look a little like this:

```
  var min = new Mock<YourObject>();
  var max = new Mock<YourObject>();
  var val = new Mock<YourObject>();

  var range = new Range<YourObject>(min.Object, max.Object);

  min.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(-1);
  max.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(1);
  Assert.True(range.Contains(val.Object));

  min.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(0);
  max.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(1);
  Assert.True(range.Contains(val.Object));

  min.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(-1);
  max.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(0);
  Assert.True(range.Contains(val.Object));


  min.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(1);
  max.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(1);
  Assert.False(range.Contains(val.Object));

  min.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(-1);
  max.Setup(m => m.CompareTo(It.IsAny<YourObject>())).Returns(-1);
  Assert.False(range.Contains(val.Object));
```

Now you are testing your Range class's Contains method and not the object's ability to return the correct value when it's CompareTo is called.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Or like chandler stated use a built in object that implements IComparable, like int, which is simple and you can trust the Int32.CompareTo(int value).  I mean if you like readable tests and all ;)